# C# и язык ввода с клавиатуры

Tags: c#

Нахожу окно с заголовком `test`, переключаю на него фокус:

```
IntPtr Handle = FindWindow(null, "test");
SetForegroundWindow(Handle);
```

И теперь мне нужно отправить в окно текст "`/test 12345`", первым символом обязательно слеш. Язык системы в момент отправки неизвестен, но и фиг с ним, мне ж нужен английский:

```
InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage = InputLanguage.FromCulture(new CultureInfo("en-US"));
```

после чего отправляю нажатия кнопок:

```
SendKeys.SendWait("/test 12345");
```

А окно получает "`.еуые 12345`".
При этом язык системы в трее отображается как русский. Если вручную, перед отправкой клавиш из моей программы, переключить язык в конечном окне на англ, то все приходит как нужно, а значит "InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage" не срабатывает, либо я использую его неправильно и он меняет только раскладку, не меняя язык.

Теста ради сделал перед отправкой

```
InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage = InputLanguage.FromCulture(new CultureInfo("ru-RU"));
```

и О ЧУДО отправился текст "`/test 12345`". Опять же, теста ради, переключаю в конечном окне язык на англ, и теперь уже отправляется "`|test 12345`". И это все с учетом того, что выше в коде я сделал переключение на русскую раскладку. Нагуглил, что отправлять слеш в русской раскладке нужно через ".", отправляю "`.test 12345`" и теперь независимо от того, какой язык отображается в трее, конечное окно получает "`/test 12345`". Вроде бы то что нужно, НО! программой пользуются и иностранцы, у которых нет русского языка в системе, и они получают "`.test 12345`". Абсурд... Я в замешательстве.

Передать текст в данное окно другим способом, кроме как имитируя нажатия клавиш, нельзя.

Comment: По моему, абсурда никакого нет.
InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage имитирует клавиши, которые видит пользователь.
Когда мы ставим en-US и жмем английскую клавишу /, то при английском вводе будет /, а при русском .
Когда мы ставим ru-RU и жмем русскую клавишу /, то при английском вводе будет |, а при русском /. (отметьте, что в данном случае подразумевается ещё и нажатие Shift).

Comment: Очень странно работает этот SendKeys. http://bbs.vbstreets.ru/viewtopic.php?f=93&t=44022 - так и не разобрался...

Comment: Хм.. `CurrentInputLanguage` - это же для твоего приложения, а не для того, в которое ты посылаешь. Хотя, судя по твоему описанию, надо попробовать сделать языки одинаковыми.

Answer (score 4):

Проблема с `SendKeys`: для многоязычных сценариев эта команда не подходит. Из [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> If your application is intended for international use with a variety of keyboards, the use of Send could yield unpredictable results and should be avoided.

Вместо этого (если вы, конечно, под Windows) нужно пользоваться напрямую WinAPI-командой [`SendInput`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). P/Invoke-сигнатуру можно подсмотреть на [pinvoke.net](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/SendInput.html):

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
internal static extern uint SendInput(
    uint nInputs,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray), In] INPUT[] pInputs,
    int cbSize);
```

`SendInput` может делать много разных хитрых штук, но для нашего случая мы должны симулировать лишь юникодный ввод, т. к. он не зависит от выбранной раскладки. Поэтому код заметно упрощается:

```
INPUT CreateUnicodeInput(char c)
{
    return
        new INPUT()
        {
            type = INPUT_TYPE.INPUT_KEYBOARD,
            U =
            {
                ki = new KEYBDINPUT()
                {
                    wScan = (ScanCodeShort)(short)c,
                    wVk = 0,
                    dwFlags = KEYEVENTF.UNICODE
                }
            }
        };
}

var inputs = "/test 12345 ляляфафа".Select(CreateUnicodeInput).ToArray();
SendInput((uint)inputs.Length, inputs, INPUT.Size);
```

Недостающие структуры данных (также с pinvoke.net):

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct INPUT
{
    internal INPUT_TYPE type;
    internal InputUnion U;
    internal static int Size
    {
        get { return Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(INPUT)); }
    }
}

internal enum INPUT_TYPE : uint
{
    INPUT_MOUSE = 0,
    INPUT_KEYBOARD = 1,
    INPUT_HARDWARE = 2
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
internal struct InputUnion
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    internal MOUSEINPUT mi;
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    internal KEYBDINPUT ki;
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    internal HARDWAREINPUT hi;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
internal struct MOUSEINPUT
{
    internal int dx;
    internal int dy;
    internal int mouseData;
    internal MOUSEEVENTF dwFlags; // uint
    internal uint time;
    internal UIntPtr dwExtraInfo;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
internal struct KEYBDINPUT
{
    internal VirtualKeyShort wVk; // short
    internal ScanCodeShort wScan; // short
    internal KEYEVENTF dwFlags;
    internal int time;
    internal UIntPtr dwExtraInfo;
}

[Flags]
internal enum KEYEVENTF : uint
{
    EXTENDEDKEY = 0x0001,
    KEYUP = 0x0002,
    SCANCODE = 0x0008,
    UNICODE = 0x0004
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
internal struct HARDWAREINPUT
{
    internal int uMsg;
    internal short wParamL;
    internal short wParamH;
}
```

Для ваших целей в принципе достаточно и этого (отсутствующие типы можно без потери корректности заменить на то, что в комментарии после их объявления). Но для полноты ответа приведу и типы, не нужные для конкретно вашего решения; возможно, они пригодятся кому-то ещё:

```
[Flags]
internal enum MOUSEEVENTF : uint
{
    ABSOLUTE = 0x8000,
    HWHEEL = 0x01000,
    MOVE = 0x0001,
    MOVE_NOCOALESCE = 0x2000,
    LEFTDOWN = 0x0002,
    LEFTUP = 0x0004,
    RIGHTDOWN = 0x0008,
    RIGHTUP = 0x0010,
    MIDDLEDOWN = 0x0020,
    MIDDLEUP = 0x0040,
    VIRTUALDESK = 0x4000,
    WHEEL = 0x0800,
    XDOWN = 0x0080,
    XUP = 0x0100
}

internal enum VirtualKeyShort : short
{
    ///<summary>
    ///Left mouse button
    ///</summary>
    LBUTTON = 0x01,
    ///<summary>
    ///Right mouse button
    ///</summary>
    RBUTTON = 0x02,
    ///<summary>
    ///Control-break processing
    ///</summary>
    CANCEL = 0x03,
    ///<summary>
    ///Middle mouse button (three-button mouse)
    ///</summary>
    MBUTTON = 0x04,
    ///<summary>
    ///Windows 2000/XP: X1 mouse button
    ///</summary>
    XBUTTON1 = 0x05,
    ///<summary>
    ///Windows 2000/XP: X2 mouse button
    ///</summary>
    XBUTTON2 = 0x06,
    ///<summary>
    ///BACKSPACE key
    ///</summary>
    BACK = 0x08,
    ///<summary>
    ///TAB key
    ///</summary>
    TAB = 0x09,
    ///<summary>
    ///CLEAR key
    ///</summary>
    CLEAR = 0x0C,
    ///<summary>
    ///ENTER key
    ///</summary>
    RETURN = 0x0D,
    ///<summary>
    ///SHIFT key
    ///</summary>
    SHIFT = 0x10,
    ///<summary>
    ///CTRL key
    ///</summary>
    CONTROL = 0x11,
    ///<summary>
    ///ALT key
    ///</summary>
    MENU = 0x12,
    ///<summary>
    ///PAUSE key
    ///</summary>
    PAUSE = 0x13,
    ///<summary>
    ///CAPS LOCK key
    ///</summary>
    CAPITAL = 0x14,
    ///<summary>
    ///Input Method Editor (IME) Kana mode
    ///</summary>
    KANA = 0x15,
    ///<summary>
    ///IME Hangul mode
    ///</summary>
    HANGUL = 0x15,
    ///<summary>
    ///IME Junja mode
    ///</summary>
    JUNJA = 0x17,
    ///<summary>
    ///IME final mode
    ///</summary>
    FINAL = 0x18,
    ///<summary>
    ///IME Hanja mode
    ///</summary>
    HANJA = 0x19,
    ///<summary>
    ///IME Kanji mode
    ///</summary>
    KANJI = 0x19,
    ///<summary>
    ///ESC key
    ///</summary>
    ESCAPE = 0x1B,
    ///<summary>
    ///IME convert
    ///</summary>
    CONVERT = 0x1C,
    ///<summary>
    ///IME nonconvert
    ///</summary>
    NONCONVERT = 0x1D,
    ///<summary>
    ///IME accept
    ///</summary>
    ACCEPT = 0x1E,
    ///<summary>
    ///IME mode change request
    ///</summary>
    MODECHANGE = 0x1F,
    ///<summary>
    ///SPACEBAR
    ///</summary>
    SPACE = 0x20,
    ///<summary>
    ///PAGE UP key
    ///</summary>
    PRIOR = 0x21,
    ///<summary>
    ///PAGE DOWN key
    ///</summary>
    NEXT = 0x22,
    ///<summary>
    ///END key
    ///</summary>
    END = 0x23,
    ///<summary>
    ///HOME key
    ///</summary>
    HOME = 0x24,
    ///<summary>
    ///LEFT ARROW key
    ///</summary>
    LEFT = 0x25,
    ///<summary>
    ///UP ARROW key
    ///</summary>
    UP = 0x26,
    ///<summary>
    ///RIGHT ARROW key
    ///</summary>
    RIGHT = 0x27,
    ///<summary>
    ///DOWN ARROW key
    ///</summary>
    DOWN = 0x28,
    ///<summary>
    ///SELECT key
    ///</summary>
    SELECT = 0x29,
    ///<summary>
    ///PRINT key
    ///</summary>
    PRINT = 0x2A,
    ///<summary>
    ///EXECUTE key
    ///</summary>
    EXECUTE = 0x2B,
    ///<summary>
    ///PRINT SCREEN key
    ///</summary>
    SNAPSHOT = 0x2C,
    ///<summary>
    ///INS key
    ///</summary>
    INSERT = 0x2D,
    ///<summary>
    ///DEL key
    ///</summary>
    DELETE = 0x2E,
    ///<summary>
    ///HELP key
    ///</summary>
    HELP = 0x2F,
    ///<summary>
    ///0 key
    ///</summary>
    KEY_0 = 0x30,
    ///<summary>
    ///1 key
    ///</summary>
    KEY_1 = 0x31,
    ///<summary>
    ///2 key
    ///</summary>
    KEY_2 = 0x32,
    ///<summary>
    ///3 key
    ///</summary>
    KEY_3 = 0x33,
    ///<summary>
    ///4 key
    ///</summary>
    KEY_4 = 0x34,
    ///<summary>
    ///5 key
    ///</summary>
    KEY_5 = 0x35,
    ///<summary>
    ///6 key
    ///</summary>
    KEY_6 = 0x36,
    ///<summary>
    ///7 key
    ///</summary>
    KEY_7 = 0x37,
    ///<summary>
    ///8 key
    ///</summary>
    KEY_8 = 0x38,
    ///<summary>
    ///9 key
    ///</summary>
    KEY_9 = 0x39,
    ///<summary>
    ///A key
    ///</summary>
    KEY_A = 0x41,
    ///<summary>
    ///B key
    ///</summary>
    KEY_B = 0x42,
    ///<summary>
    ///C key
    ///</summary>
    KEY_C = 0x43,
    ///<summary>
    ///D key
    ///</summary>
    KEY_D = 0x44,
    ///<summary>
    ///E key
    ///</summary>
    KEY_E = 0x45,
    ///<summary>
    ///F key
    ///</summary>
    KEY_F = 0x46,
    ///<summary>
    ///G key
    ///</summary>
    KEY_G = 0x47,
    ///<summary>
    ///H key
    ///</summary>
    KEY_H = 0x48,
    ///<summary>
    ///I key
    ///</summary>
    KEY_I = 0x49,
    ///<summary>
    ///J key
    ///</summary>
    KEY_J = 0x4A,
    ///<summary>
    ///K key
    ///</summary>
    KEY_K = 0x4B,
    ///<summary>
    ///L key
    ///</summary>
    KEY_L = 0x4C,
    ///<summary>
    ///M key
    ///</summary>
    KEY_M = 0x4D,
    ///<summary>
    ///N key
    ///</summary>
    KEY_N = 0x4E,
    ///<summary>
    ///O key
    ///</summary>
    KEY_O = 0x4F,
    ///<summary>
    ///P key
    ///</summary>
    KEY_P = 0x50,
    ///<summary>
    ///Q key
    ///</summary>
    KEY_Q = 0x51,
    ///<summary>
    ///R key
    ///</summary>
    KEY_R = 0x52,
    ///<summary>
    ///S key
    ///</summary>
    KEY_S = 0x53,
    ///<summary>
    ///T key
    ///</summary>
    KEY_T = 0x54,
    ///<summary>
    ///U key
    ///</summary>
    KEY_U = 0x55,
    ///<summary>
    ///V key
    ///</summary>
    KEY_V = 0x56,
    ///<summary>
    ///W key
    ///</summary>
    KEY_W = 0x57,
    ///<summary>
    ///X key
    ///</summary>
    KEY_X = 0x58,
    ///<summary>
    ///Y key
    ///</summary>
    KEY_Y = 0x59,
    ///<summary>
    ///Z key
    ///</summary>
    KEY_Z = 0x5A,
    ///<summary>
    ///Left Windows key (Microsoft Natural keyboard)
    ///</summary>
    LWIN = 0x5B,
    ///<summary>
    ///Right Windows key (Natural keyboard)
    ///</summary>
    RWIN = 0x5C,
    ///<summary>
    ///Applications key (Natural keyboard)
    ///</summary>
    APPS = 0x5D,
    ///<summary>
    ///Computer Sleep key
    ///</summary>
    SLEEP = 0x5F,
    ///<summary>
    ///Numeric keypad 0 key
    ///</summary>
    NUMPAD0 = 0x60,
    ///<summary>
    ///Numeric keypad 1 key
    ///</summary>
    NUMPAD1 = 0x61,
    ///<summary>
    ///Numeric keypad 2 key
    ///</summary>
    NUMPAD2 = 0x62,
    ///<summary>
    ///Numeric keypad 3 key
    ///</summary>
    NUMPAD3 = 0x63,
    ///<summary>
    ///Numeric keypad 4 key
    ///</summary>
    NUMPAD4 = 0x64,
    ///<summary>
    ///Numeric keypad 5 key
    ///</summary>
    NUMPAD5 = 0x65,
    ///<summary>
    ///Numeric keypad 6 key
    ///</summary>
    NUMPAD6 = 0x66,
    ///<summary>
    ///Numeric keypad 7 key
    ///</summary>
    NUMPAD7 = 0x67,
    ///<summary>
    ///Numeric keypad 8 key
    ///</summary>
    NUMPAD8 = 0x68,
    ///<summary>
    ///Numeric keypad 9 key
    ///</summary>
    NUMPAD9 = 0x69,
    ///<summary>
    ///Multiply key
    ///</summary>
    MULTIPLY = 0x6A,
    ///<summary>
    ///Add key
    ///</summary>
    ADD = 0x6B,
    ///<summary>
    ///Separator key
    ///</summary>
    SEPARATOR = 0x6C,
    ///<summary>
    ///Subtract key
    ///</summary>
    SUBTRACT = 0x6D,
    ///<summary>
    ///Decimal key
    ///</summary>
    DECIMAL = 0x6E,
    ///<summary>
    ///Divide key
    ///</summary>
    DIVIDE = 0x6F,
    ///<summary>
    ///F1 key
    ///</summary>
    F1 = 0x70,
    ///<summary>
    ///F2 key
    ///</summary>
    F2 = 0x71,
    ///<summary>
    ///F3 key
    ///</summary>
    F3 = 0x72,
    ///<summary>
    ///F4 key
    ///</summary>
    F4 = 0x73,
    ///<summary>
    ///F5 key
    ///</summary>
    F5 = 0x74,
    ///<summary>
    ///F6 key
    ///</summary>
    F6 = 0x75,
    ///<summary>
    ///F7 key
    ///</summary>
    F7 = 0x76,
    ///<summary>
    ///F8 key
    ///</summary>
    F8 = 0x77,
    ///<summary>
    ///F9 key
    ///</summary>
    F9 = 0x78,
    ///<summary>
    ///F10 key
    ///</summary>
    F10 = 0x79,
    ///<summary>
    ///F11 key
    ///</summary>
    F11 = 0x7A,
    ///<summary>
    ///F12 key
    ///</summary>
    F12 = 0x7B,
    ///<summary>
    ///F13 key
    ///</summary>
    F13 = 0x7C,
    ///<summary>
    ///F14 key
    ///</summary>
    F14 = 0x7D,
    ///<summary>
    ///F15 key
    ///</summary>
    F15 = 0x7E,
    ///<summary>
    ///F16 key
    ///</summary>
    F16 = 0x7F,
    ///<summary>
    ///F17 key  
    ///</summary>
    F17 = 0x80,
    ///<summary>
    ///F18 key  
    ///</summary>
    F18 = 0x81,
    ///<summary>
    ///F19 key  
    ///</summary>
    F19 = 0x82,
    ///<summary>
    ///F20 key  
    ///</summary>
    F20 = 0x83,
    ///<summary>
    ///F21 key  
    ///</summary>
    F21 = 0x84,
    ///<summary>
    ///F22 key, (PPC only) Key used to lock device.
    ///</summary>
    F22 = 0x85,
    ///<summary>
    ///F23 key  
    ///</summary>
    F23 = 0x86,
    ///<summary>
    ///F24 key  
    ///</summary>
    F24 = 0x87,
    ///<summary>
    ///NUM LOCK key
    ///</summary>
    NUMLOCK = 0x90,
    ///<summary>
    ///SCROLL LOCK key
    ///</summary>
    SCROLL = 0x91,
    ///<summary>
    ///Left SHIFT key
    ///</summary>
    LSHIFT = 0xA0,
    ///<summary>
    ///Right SHIFT key
    ///</summary>
    RSHIFT = 0xA1,
    ///<summary>
    ///Left CONTROL key
    ///</summary>
    LCONTROL = 0xA2,
    ///<summary>
    ///Right CONTROL key
    ///</summary>
    RCONTROL = 0xA3,
    ///<summary>
    ///Left MENU key
    ///</summary>
    LMENU = 0xA4,
    ///<summary>
    ///Right MENU key
    ///</summary>
    RMENU = 0xA5,
    ///<summary>
    ///Windows 2000/XP: Browser Back key
    ///</summary>
    BROWSER_BACK = 0xA6,
    ///<summary>
    ///Windows 2000/XP: Browser Forward key
    ///</summary>
    BROWSER_FORWARD = 0xA7,
    ///<summary>
    ///Windows 2000/XP: Browser Refresh key
    ///</summary>
    BROWSER_REFRESH = 0xA8,
    ///<summary>
    ///Windows 2000/XP: Browser Stop key
    ///</summary>
    BROWSER_STOP = 0xA9,
    ///<summary>
    ///Windows 2000/XP: Browser Search key
    ///</summary>
    BROWSER_SEARCH = 0xAA,
    ///<summary>
    ///Windows 2000/XP: Browser Favorites key
    ///</summary>
    BROWSER_FAVORITES = 0xAB,
    ///<summary>
    ///Windows 2000/XP: Browser Start and Home key
    ///</summary>
    BROWSER_HOME = 0xAC,
    ///<summary>
    ///Windows 2000/XP: Volume Mute key
    ///</summary>
    VOLUME_MUTE = 0xAD,
    ///<summary>
    ///Windows 2000/XP: Volume Down key
    ///</summary>
    VOLUME_DOWN = 0xAE,
    ///<summary>
    ///Windows 2000/XP: Volume Up key
    ///</summary>
    VOLUME_UP = 0xAF,
    ///<summary>
    ///Windows 2000/XP: Next Track key
    ///</summary>
    MEDIA_NEXT_TRACK = 0xB0,
    ///<summary>
    ///Windows 2000/XP: Previous Track key
    ///</summary>
    MEDIA_PREV_TRACK = 0xB1,
    ///<summary>
    ///Windows 2000/XP: Stop Media key
    ///</summary>
    MEDIA_STOP = 0xB2,
    ///<summary>
    ///Windows 2000/XP: Play/Pause Media key
    ///</summary>
    MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE = 0xB3,
    ///<summary>
    ///Windows 2000/XP: Start Mail key
    ///</summary>
    LAUNCH_MAIL = 0xB4,
    ///<summary>
    ///Windows 2000/XP: Select Media key
    ///</summary>
    LAUNCH_MEDIA_SELECT = 0xB5,
    ///<summary>
    ///Windows 2000/XP: Start Application 1 key
    ///</summary>
    LAUNCH_APP1 = 0xB6,
    ///<summary>
    ///Windows 2000/XP: Start Application 2 key
    ///</summary>
    LAUNCH_APP2 = 0xB7,
    ///<summary>
    ///Used for miscellaneous characters; it can vary by keyboard.
    ///</summary>
    OEM_1 = 0xBA,
    ///<summary>
    ///Windows 2000/XP: For any country/region, the '+' key
    ///</summary>
    OEM_PLUS = 0xBB,
    ///<summary>
    ///Windows 2000/XP: For any country/region, the ',' key
    ///</summary>
    OEM_COMMA = 0xBC,
    ///<summary>
    ///Windows 2000/XP: For any country/region, the '-' key
    ///</summary>
    OEM_MINUS = 0xBD,
    ///<summary>
    ///Windows 2000/XP: For any country/region, the '.' key
    ///</summary>
    OEM_PERIOD = 0xBE,
    ///<summary>
    ///Used for miscellaneous characters; it can vary by keyboard.
    ///</summary>
    OEM_2 = 0xBF,
    ///<summary>
    ///Used for miscellaneous characters; it can vary by keyboard.
    ///</summary>
    OEM_3 = 0xC0,
    ///<summary>
    ///Used for miscellaneous characters; it can vary by keyboard.
    ///</summary>
    OEM_4 = 0xDB,
    ///<summary>
    ///Used for miscellaneous characters; it can vary by keyboard.
    ///</summary>
    OEM_5 = 0xDC,
    ///<summary>
    ///Used for miscellaneous characters; it can vary by keyboard.
    ///</summary>
    OEM_6 = 0xDD,
    ///<summary>
    ///Used for miscellaneous characters; it can vary by keyboard.
    ///</summary>
    OEM_7 = 0xDE,
    ///<summary>
    ///Used for miscellaneous characters; it can vary by keyboard.
    ///</summary>
    OEM_8 = 0xDF,
    ///<summary>
    ///Windows 2000/XP: Either the angle bracket key or the backslash key on the RT 102-key keyboard
    ///</summary>
    OEM_102 = 0xE2,
    ///<summary>
    ///Windows 95/98/Me, Windows NT 4.0, Windows 2000/XP: IME PROCESS key
    ///</summary>
    PROCESSKEY = 0xE5,
    ///<summary>
    ///Windows 2000/XP: Used to pass Unicode characters as if they were keystrokes.
    ///The VK_PACKET key is the low word of a 32-bit Virtual Key value used for non-keyboard input methods. For more information,
    ///see Remark in KEYBDINPUT, SendInput, WM_KEYDOWN, and WM_KEYUP
    ///</summary>
    PACKET = 0xE7,
    ///<summary>
    ///Attn key
    ///</summary>
    ATTN = 0xF6,
    ///<summary>
    ///CrSel key
    ///</summary>
    CRSEL = 0xF7,
    ///<summary>
    ///ExSel key
    ///</summary>
    EXSEL = 0xF8,
    ///<summary>
    ///Erase EOF key
    ///</summary>
    EREOF = 0xF9,
    ///<summary>
    ///Play key
    ///</summary>
    PLAY = 0xFA,
    ///<summary>
    ///Zoom key
    ///</summary>
    ZOOM = 0xFB,
    ///<summary>
    ///Reserved
    ///</summary>
    NONAME = 0xFC,
    ///<summary>
    ///PA1 key
    ///</summary>
    PA1 = 0xFD,
    ///<summary>
    ///Clear key
    ///</summary>
    OEM_CLEAR = 0xFE
}

internal enum ScanCodeShort : short
{
    LBUTTON = 0,
    RBUTTON = 0,
    CANCEL = 70,
    MBUTTON = 0,
    XBUTTON1 = 0,
    XBUTTON2 = 0,
    BACK = 14,
    TAB = 15,
    CLEAR = 76,
    RETURN = 28,
    SHIFT = 42,
    CONTROL = 29,
    MENU = 56,
    PAUSE = 0,
    CAPITAL = 58,
    KANA = 0,
    HANGUL = 0,
    JUNJA = 0,
    FINAL = 0,
    HANJA = 0,
    KANJI = 0,
    ESCAPE = 1,
    CONVERT = 0,
    NONCONVERT = 0,
    ACCEPT = 0,
    MODECHANGE = 0,
    SPACE = 57,
    PRIOR = 73,
    NEXT = 81,
    END = 79,
    HOME = 71,
    LEFT = 75,
    UP = 72,
    RIGHT = 77,
    DOWN = 80,
    SELECT = 0,
    PRINT = 0,
    EXECUTE = 0,
    SNAPSHOT = 84,
    INSERT = 82,
    DELETE = 83,
    HELP = 99,
    KEY_0 = 11,
    KEY_1 = 2,
    KEY_2 = 3,
    KEY_3 = 4,
    KEY_4 = 5,
    KEY_5 = 6,
    KEY_6 = 7,
    KEY_7 = 8,
    KEY_8 = 9,
    KEY_9 = 10,
    KEY_A = 30,
    KEY_B = 48,
    KEY_C = 46,
    KEY_D = 32,
    KEY_E = 18,
    KEY_F = 33,
    KEY_G = 34,
    KEY_H = 35,
    KEY_I = 23,
    KEY_J = 36,
    KEY_K = 37,
    KEY_L = 38,
    KEY_M = 50,
    KEY_N = 49,
    KEY_O = 24,
    KEY_P = 25,
    KEY_Q = 16,
    KEY_R = 19,
    KEY_S = 31,
    KEY_T = 20,
    KEY_U = 22,
    KEY_V = 47,
    KEY_W = 17,
    KEY_X = 45,
    KEY_Y = 21,
    KEY_Z = 44,
    LWIN = 91,
    RWIN = 92,
    APPS = 93,
    SLEEP = 95,
    NUMPAD0 = 82,
    NUMPAD1 = 79,
    NUMPAD2 = 80,
    NUMPAD3 = 81,
    NUMPAD4 = 75,
    NUMPAD5 = 76,
    NUMPAD6 = 77,
    NUMPAD7 = 71,
    NUMPAD8 = 72,
    NUMPAD9 = 73,
    MULTIPLY = 55,
    ADD = 78,
    SEPARATOR = 0,
    SUBTRACT = 74,
    DECIMAL = 83,
    DIVIDE = 53,
    F1 = 59,
    F2 = 60,
    F3 = 61,
    F4 = 62,
    F5 = 63,
    F6 = 64,
    F7 = 65,
    F8 = 66,
    F9 = 67,
    F10 = 68,
    F11 = 87,
    F12 = 88,
    F13 = 100,
    F14 = 101,
    F15 = 102,
    F16 = 103,
    F17 = 104,
    F18 = 105,
    F19 = 106,
    F20 = 107,
    F21 = 108,
    F22 = 109,
    F23 = 110,
    F24 = 118,
    NUMLOCK = 69,
    SCROLL = 70,
    LSHIFT = 42,
    RSHIFT = 54,
    LCONTROL = 29,
    RCONTROL = 29,
    LMENU = 56,
    RMENU = 56,
    BROWSER_BACK = 106,
    BROWSER_FORWARD = 105,
    BROWSER_REFRESH = 103,
    BROWSER_STOP = 104,
    BROWSER_SEARCH = 101,
    BROWSER_FAVORITES = 102,
    BROWSER_HOME = 50,
    VOLUME_MUTE = 32,
    VOLUME_DOWN = 46,
    VOLUME_UP = 48,
    MEDIA_NEXT_TRACK = 25,
    MEDIA_PREV_TRACK = 16,
    MEDIA_STOP = 36,
    MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE = 34,
    LAUNCH_MAIL = 108,
    LAUNCH_MEDIA_SELECT = 109,
    LAUNCH_APP1 = 107,
    LAUNCH_APP2 = 33,
    OEM_1 = 39,
    OEM_PLUS = 13,
    OEM_COMMA = 51,
    OEM_MINUS = 12,
    OEM_PERIOD = 52,
    OEM_2 = 53,
    OEM_3 = 41,
    OEM_4 = 26,
    OEM_5 = 43,
    OEM_6 = 27,
    OEM_7 = 40,
    OEM_8 = 0,
    OEM_102 = 86,
    PROCESSKEY = 0,
    PACKET = 0,
    ATTN = 0,
    CRSEL = 0,
    EXSEL = 0,
    EREOF = 93,
    PLAY = 0,
    ZOOM = 98,
    NONAME = 0,
    PA1 = 0,
    OEM_CLEAR = 0,
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Я бы попробовал подогнать текст под `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`, она всегда и везде одинаковая должна быть.